# How do you factor $3x^{\frac{3}{2}}-9x^{\frac{1}{2}}+6x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you factor $$3x^{{3}/{2}}-9x^{{1}/{2}}+6x^{-{1}/{2}}?$$

I'm trying to self teach myself, and I can't find any examples of this kind of problem anywhere online.

Comment: hint: try multiplying the expression by $$\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^{1/2}}$$

Comment: It would be good to use parentheses.  I am sure that by 3x^3/2 you meant the $3x^{\frac 32}$ that was edited in, but the "official" reading based on operator precedence would be $\frac {3x^3}2$.  Even better, use MathJax.  A starter tutorial is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you distribute out a factor of $x^{-(1/2)}$ you get $$x^{-(1/2)}(3x^2-9x+6)$$ and the quadratic may be something more familiar.

Answer (score 1):

$$3x^{{3}/{2}}-9x^{{1}/{2}}+6x^{-{1}/{2}} = 
3x^{-1/2}\left( x^2 -3x + 2\right) = \frac{3\left( x^2 -3x + 2\right)}{\sqrt x}$$

can you factor the quadratic in the numerator?